# Unable to download packages from an Artifactory Debian varnish41 remote repository

Tags: debian, package, artifactory, varnish, apt-get

I’ve added a `debian-varnish41-remote` repository to Artifactory with this URL: https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41. The test button says everything is OK.

In the client, I ran these commands with success:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list" 

curl -L https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/gpgkey | apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
```

But `sudo apt-get install varnish` ends up with an HTTP 400 error (error 400 is Bad Request).

```
$ sudo apt-get install varnish
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  varnish
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,958 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,921 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Err https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/ trusty/main varnish amd64 4.1.9-1~trusty
  HttpError400
E: Failed to fetch https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish (4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb  HttpError400

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Setting *Bypass HEAD Requests* has the same result.

---

Now, here are the things we tested while attempting to troubleshoot:

**Does Artifactory have any permissions limiting downloads from that repo?**

Repo permissions were lowered as much as possible. We are able to download the package from my browser without signing into Artifactory. So this does not seem to be the issue.

**Are the Release or Package files in the repos different?**

We tried looking at the `InRelease` and `Packages` files provided by both Varnish and Artifactory to see if they were different in any way. They are both identical. It appears Artifactory only forwards the files from their remote location.

**Is that package actually available on that URL?**

Downloading the package directly from Artifactory by using the above URL does work:

```
$ wget 'https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish (4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb'
--2017-12-29 22:48:47--  https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish%20(4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb
Resolving <my-artifactory-server> (<my-artifactory-server>)... <my server IP>
Connecting to <my-artifactory-server> (<my-artifactory-server>)|<my server IP>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1958382 (1.9M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb’

100%[============================================================================>] 1,958,382   3.32MB/s   in 0.6s

2017-12-29 22:48:48 (3.32 MB/s) - ‘varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb’ saved [1958382/1958382]
```

**That URL has a space and a few parentheses. Could this be messing up the URL?**

Looking at the URLs apt-get uses for downloading the packages does not seem to indicate any differences:

*Artifactory:*

```
$ apt-get download --print-uris varnish
'https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish (4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb' varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb 1958382 SHA512:1a712315ccf01a7babe17f1cf8876a1d04fba16472c00759c7d63bb3f11839e6b450dcbc4541b7d07104eba600b7a835fb8d1067280eb83ede9665192aa7bf06

$ apt-get download varnish
Err https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/ trusty/main varnish amd64 4.1.9-1~trusty
  HttpError400
E: Failed to fetch https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish (4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb  HttpError400
```

*Varnish:*

```
$ apt-get download --print-uris varnish
'https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/ubuntu/pool/trusty/main/v/varnish (4.1.9-1)/varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb' varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb 1958382 SHA512:1a712315ccf01a7babe17f1cf8876a1d04fba16472c00759c7d63bb3f11839e6b450dcbc4541b7d07104eba600b7a835fb8d1067280eb83ede9665192aa7bf06

$ apt-get download varnish

$ ls
varnish_4.1.9-1~trusty_amd64.deb
```

This last subheading has our main concern about this issue. Is Artifactory handling spaces in the URLs well?

Thank you very much for your help with this!

Esteban

Comment: I don't know whether Artifactory is handling the spaces properly, but have you tried URL encoding the repository name?

Comment: Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!

I'm sorry, maybe I'm not understanding you well. Are you saying that we should avoid using spaces in the URL we are adding?

If that's the case, please notice that the repo we are adding has no spaces:

`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41-remote trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"`

The spaces appear in the `Packages` file which Varnish provides:

`Filename: pool/trusty/main/libv/varnish (4.1.0-1)/libvarnishapi-dev_4.1.0-1~trusty_amd64.deb`

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't really know, but I would maybe try `deb https://<my-artifactory-server>/artifactory/debian-varnish41‌​-remote%20trusty%20main`

Comment: Thanks again. As I mentioned, the spaces appear in the `Packages` file which Varnish provides: `Filename: pool/trusty/main/libv/varnish (4.1.0-1)/libvarnishapi-dev_4.1.0-1~trusty_amd64.deb`. It's not related to the _Artifactory_ repo name itself. Thanks for any other thought.

Comment: @EstebanVidal, I'm having the same issue as you with the main ubuntu repo. Did you ever find a fix?